# Maintain italic style texts from original text document when applying regular body text paragraph style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a MS Word document that has a lot of text and some words are in italic style. When I paste the text from this document to InDesign layout, I apply regular body text paragraph style to it and then I need to clear overrides, but when I do that, the parts that were italic in original document now becomes regular. I would be very pleased if someone could tell how to fix this, so after applying regular text paragraph style I will not need to go trough all text to search which texts should be italic and this could work automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Importing text from MS Word is hell. I have no fail proof technique, but there are some tricks. Here is method for preserving italic text:

- Avoid *pasting* the text. Instead, when in a text frame, press *Ctrl+D/Cmd+D* or use *File > Place...* to *place* the text.
- Choose your file, make sure *Show Import Options* is checked and click *Open*. (.doc files work better than .docx in my experience.)
- Make sure to choose *Remove Styles and Formatting from Text and Tables*, check *Preserve Local Overrides* and click *OK*:

  [image: import options]
- Create a *Character Style* for the italic text where you choose the *Font Style* you want.
- Now use *Ctrl+F/Cmd+F* to enter *Find/Change*. We need to apply the *Character Style* you just created to every occurrence of italic text.
- First enter *Find Format* by double-clicking or clicking the tiny magnifying glass. Set *Basic Character Formats > Font Style* to *Italic* (luckily MS Word normally just use the plain *Italic* style).
- Then enter *Change Format* and set *Style Options > Character Style* to the style you just created (here I call it "My italic style") and click *Change All*.

  [image]
- Now you can select the entire text, right click and select *Clear All Overrides*. This will reset the styling to match your *Paragraph Style*, but all the occurrences of the italic *Character Style* will be preserved, even if you later change the *Paragraph Style*.

You can use the same method to preserve other styles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think copy-paste is the best way to do that if you want to keep some text styles.

Importing the Word file to Indesign, there's an option that preserve the text styles.

[image]

Once imported all the word styles are on the Indesign file and you can delete/replace/change without forcing them.

[image: styles]

On the sample gif, the blue text has a **Normal** paragraph style with many different character options. There's another paragraph style called **Mine** with just a change of color and font. When changing the paragraph style, the character options are the same.

[image: gif]
Anyway, this kind of job always need a check and it depends about how the doc file is made.

If you are forced to clear overrides, you should make a character style to all the italic words and apply to them. If you clear overrides to paragraph styles, the character styles remain without changes.